The branch coverage of the suspend method cannot reach 100%
I wrote a Kotlin code and I want to write unit tests for it. But I found that the unit test code I wrote still cannot cover 100% branch coverage. What should I do?
kotlin code:
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
    @DefaultDispatcher private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    @ApplicationScope private val scope: CoroutineScope,
    val checkService:ICheckService = CheckService()
) {
    fun fetchData(value: Int): String {
        return runBlocking(dispatcher) {
            suspendCoroutine<String> { continuation ->
                println(111)
                scope.launch(dispatcher) {
                    println(222)
                    delay(100)
                    println(333)
                    if(checkService.check(value)){
                        println(444)
                    }
                    continuation.resume("result")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

interface ICheckService {
    suspend fun check(value:Int): Boolean
}

class CheckService:ICheckService{
    override suspend fun check(value: Int): Boolean {
        // mock delay
        delay(300)

        return value > 0
    }

}

UT code:
class MyRepositoryTest4 {
    private lateinit var myRepository: MyRepository
    private val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    private lateinit var scope: TestScope

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        scope = TestScope(dispatcher)
        myRepository = MyRepository(dispatcher, scope)
    }

    @Test
    fun testMyRepository1() = scope.runTest {

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            myRepository.fetchData(-1)
        }
    }
    @Test
    fun testMyRepository2() = scope.runTest {

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            myRepository.fetchData(1)
        }
    }
}

Additionally, if I change the object of
myRepository to myRepository=mockk (relaxed=true)

, the coverage will be 0% and no code will be executed.




